# Confused about MSIL

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I read the c# program compilation takes two steps.

First it generates MSIL and then it produces the machine code. So I am curious to see the files generated by first phase of compilation (MSIL).

I have been thinking the DLL file is the file which contains the MSIL code, but I think I am wrong.

Comment: You can use `corflags.exe`. It will return an error if the file does not have a valid managed header.

Comment: What specifically are you asking? There are several questions posed...

Comment: I read the the c# program compilation takes two steps. in first it generates MSIL and  then it produces the machine code. So i am just curious to see the files generated by first phase of compilation. I have been thinking the dll file is the file which contains the MSIL code, but i think i am wrong. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Use ILDASM.exe to open a DLL/EXE file. It's part of the framework.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707295/how-to-programatically-find-the-bytecode-cil-in-a-net-executable-dll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. .NET DLL's and EXE's (called assemblies in .NET) are the ones that contain MSIL. DLL's can have another format than the .NET ones, so that's why the .NET assemblies have a header that makes them recognizable as such. You can use `corflags.exe` to check if an DLL/EXE is a .NET DLL/EXE.

The IL code in the assembly is interpreted by the CLR (Common Language Runtime), which translates it to machine code. You can't see that step actually since it is done by the JIT'ter at runtime (or you should pre-compile the assemblies using `ngen.exe` and read the generated files).

Comment: LinqPad actually generates the IL for the code that you compile, theoretically with un -obfuscated code it's totally possible to get most of it out in "MSIL".

Comment: True, but the second step isn't. Reflection and ILDASM are the tools to use for the first step.

Comment: What do you mean with "the second step isn't"? Unless you've obfuscated the code you can reflect it and just recompile it.

Comment: ah now I get it, still morning here for me.

Answer (score 2):

.net has multiple languages (C#, VB.net etc.).

When you compile a C# project library, it outputs a dll that contains `IL` code.

C# compiles to IL as VB.net compiles to IL and therefore you can "mix up" code between to two languages.

This IL is compiled to machine code using the [JIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.90).aspx) compiler in runtime (read about the [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime)).

You can see IL code by using a reflector and reflecting a dll.

Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).